# How Random Are Pwgen's Passwords?

Tags: password

I'm looking for a good password generator and I came across pwgen. Are the passwords generated using the `pwgen -s -y` command truly random? And would you recommend pwgen?

Also, I am aware that some generators use dev/random or dev/urandom. Does pwgen use either, and what is the difference between the two?

Comment: The second part should be a separate question, at any rate, it is well addressed here: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3936/54387. Also, define "truly random".

Comment: Also related: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/101935/54387

Comment: Linux is FOSS (Free and Open Source Software). After `sudo apt-get install apt-src;man apt-src` you can `apt-src install pwgen`, and read the source. `man urandom` will explain the differences between `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`

Comment: @waltinator `man urandom` is rather overcautious (see linked [security.se] post, and http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/).

Comment: Pestering you for acceptance again as I just got another upvote and edited my answer to be even more clear...  **;-)**

Comment: My apologies, Fabby; its been a while since I used the forum. But I appreciate your answer and have marked it as Accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to get true randomness from a deterministic machine!  Any algorithm in existence today *(not using non-deterministic hardware)* generates [*pseudo*-random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness) noise, not [*true* randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness), so the answer to your question is:

#### No, the passwords generated using the `pwgen -s -y` command **are not** *truly random!*

<sub>Sorry, one of my pet-peeves: they are *very* random though... **;-)**</sub>